# sdkmanager --install "emulator" give error 'Failed to find package "emulator"'

Tags: android, emulation

I am working on windows 7 and have everything setup.
I created a AVD by using:
(1): sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
Till here everything is working well but when I am running:
(2): avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
It gives me the error:
Auto-selecting single ABI x86===========] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]
Error: "emulator" package must be installed!
null

So, I tried the command:
sdkmanager --install "emulator"

But it gives the output as:
Warning: Failed to find package 'emulator'
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...

and exits.

I'm facing this problem and also tried reinstalling everything but nothing worked.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, I've same problem Rajan. Did you find any solution for emulator ? @rajan-rajan